# Pre-shuffle aggregation in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are migrating a spark job to flink. We have used pre-shuffle aggregation in spark. Is there a way to execute similar operation in spark. We are consuming data from apache kafka. We are using keyed tumbling window to aggregate the data. We want to aggregate the data in flink before performing shuffle.

https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is possible and I will describe three ways. First the already built-in for Flink Table API. The second way you have to build your own pre-aggregate operator. The third is a dynamic pre-aggregate operator which adjusts the number of events to pre-aggregate before the shuffle phase.

**Flink Table API**

As [it is shown here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/tuning/) you can do *MiniBatch Aggregation* or *Local-Global Aggregation*. The second option is better. You basically tell to Flink to create mini-batches of every `5000` events and pre-aggregate them before the shuffle phase.

```
// instantiate table environment
TableEnvironment tEnv = ...

// access flink configuration
Configuration configuration = tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration();
// set low-level key-value options
configuration.setString("table.exec.mini-batch.enabled", "true");
configuration.setString("table.exec.mini-batch.allow-latency", "5 s");
configuration.setString("table.exec.mini-batch.size", "5000");
configuration.setString("table.optimizer.agg-phase-strategy", "TWO_PHASE");
```

**Flink Stream API**

This way is more cumbersome because you have to create your own operator using `OneInputStreamOperator` and call it using the [doTransform()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#doTransform-java.lang.String-org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorFactory-). Here is the example of the BundleOperator.

```
public abstract class AbstractMapStreamBundleOperator<K, V, IN, OUT>
  extends AbstractUdfStreamOperator<OUT, MapBundleFunction<K, V, IN, OUT>>
  implements OneInputStreamOperator<IN, OUT>, BundleTriggerCallback {
@Override
 public void processElement(StreamRecord<IN> element) throws Exception {
  // get the key and value for the map bundle
  final IN input = element.getValue();
  final K bundleKey = getKey(input);
  final V bundleValue = this.bundle.get(bundleKey);

  // get a new value after adding this element to bundle
  final V newBundleValue = userFunction.addInput(bundleValue, input);

  // update to map bundle
  bundle.put(bundleKey, newBundleValue);

  numOfElements++;
  bundleTrigger.onElement(input);
 }

 @Override
 public void finishBundle() throws Exception {
  if (!bundle.isEmpty()) {
   numOfElements = 0;
   userFunction.finishBundle(bundle, collector);
   bundle.clear();
  }
  bundleTrigger.reset();
 }
}
```

The call-back interface defines when you are going to trigger the pre-aggregate. Every time that the stream reaches the bundle limit at `if (count >= maxCount)` your pre-aggregate operator will emit events to the shuffle phase.

```
public class CountBundleTrigger<T> implements BundleTrigger<T> {
 private final long maxCount;
 private transient BundleTriggerCallback callback;
 private transient long count = 0;

 public CountBundleTrigger(long maxCount) {
  Preconditions.checkArgument(maxCount > 0, "maxCount must be greater than 0");
  this.maxCount = maxCount;
 }

 @Override
 public void registerCallback(BundleTriggerCallback callback) {
  this.callback = Preconditions.checkNotNull(callback, "callback is null");
 }

 @Override
 public void onElement(T element) throws Exception {
  count++;
  if (count >= maxCount) {
   callback.finishBundle();
   reset();
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void reset() {
  count = 0;
 }
}
```

Then you call your operator using the `doTransform`:

```
myStream.map(....)
 .doTransform(metricCombiner, info, new RichMapStreamBundleOperator<>(myMapBundleFunction, bundleTrigger, keyBundleSelector))
 .map(...)
 .keyBy(...)
 .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(20)))
```

**A dynamic pre-aggregation**

In case you wish to have a dynamic pre-aggregate operator check the [AdCom - Adaptive Combiner for stream aggregation](https://github.com/TU-Berlin-DIMA/AdCom). It basically adjusts the pre-aggregation based on backpressure signals. It results in using the maximum possible of the shuffle phase.

Comment: Looks like adcom needs recompilation of flink project.

Comment: Yes. It is implemented in such a way that you can call `yourStream.adcom(....)`. That is because the JobManager adjusts the `AdCom` parameter in all TaskManagers. However you can get the code and use at the original Flink `doTransform(...)` without the dynamic adjustment.